# How can i customize look of Sharepoint LIST Modern View

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, list, list-view, custom-list

I wanted to customize the modern look of a Sharepoint list view as one of my user is using the List for approval and it doesn't seem so user friendly as compared to web portals. For example,
if i can insert/edit buttons on this ribbon,if i can an Approval button that will also be fine
[image: list ribbion]

Similarly if i can make customisations like adding picture,name of user etc in the left pane :
[image: left side pane]

that will also be fine.Actually i wanted to do a complete makeover for this ,if possible
Any helps will be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Currently you can customize the list view in following ways.

1. [Column Formatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting) - Format a specific column in the view
2. [View Formatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-formatting) - Can customize the entire view
3. [ListView Command Sets](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-cmdset-with-dialog-api) - Using SPfx command set allows you to add custom buttons to the toolbar.